# OpenGL downscaling smoothing

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using big texture (for example, X*10, Y*10, where X and Y are screen dimensions) and draw it on screen. It reduces 10 times. It uses GL_LINEAR interpolation for min and mag, but interpolation does not work. If I use texture only 1x or 2x as screen size, then interpolation works, but it is bigger, interpolation does not work. I don't want to use mipmaps, because they breaks clarity of texture. How do I correctly downscale image with smoothing?

Comment: re: mipmap clarity, are you generating your own mipmap chain [with gamma-correction & filtering](http://number-none.com/product/Mipmapping,%20Part%202/index.html) or are you using whatever `glGenerateMipmap()` plops out?

Comment: I'm using glGenerateMipmap(). 
Have read about multisampling, but can't get it to work in framebuffer. Followed all "instructions", but get only black screen. 
Tried this, this, this, and this...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878216/opengl-how-to-draw-to-a-multisample-framebuffer-and-then-use-the-result-as-a-n
https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling
http://wangchuan.github.io/coding/2016/05/26/multisampling-fbo.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482851/how-to-use-multisampling-with-opengl-fbos

Comment: About manual creation of mipmaps didn't found. And resolution of mipmaps should be the power of 2? If original image's resolution is not power of 2. Didn't found how to control which mipmap to display. I think, automatically selected the mipmap that is slightly lower resolution (blurry). Only "min" and "max" level can be controlled, but can't be controlled at which distance (zoom) which level will be shown, what results in (blurry) or (no smoothing) if too high level is set.